# O que é preciso para aprender classes e métodos específicos para uma tarefa?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, classes, documentação

O que preciso para aprender sobre classes e métodos em geral para programação Java e Android?

Por exemplo: se eu precisar exibir um PDF, **como** vou aprender a fazer isso?

Sabemos que existe varias classes, ninguém aqui conseguiria escrever todas as classes para me explicar sobre todas elas, "no Youtube" também não conseguiria achar, também sabemos que conteúdo explicativo sobre todas classes e métodos não se encontra em qualquer site.

Então, o que é preciso para aprender sobre classes e métodos? Dessa forma, se por exemplo, em um determinado trabalho eu precisasse da classe `MediaPlayer`, eu já teria aprendido como utiliza-la.

Comment: Pergunta sendo debatida em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5965/101.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tudo o que pode usar está documentado. Pelo menos em bibliotecas que valem a pena usar. Toda informação básica do uso das classes está lá. Obviamente os métodos delas também.

O [Android tem um site dedicado a isto](https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html). Tem que saber usar muito bem este site. Tem que ter uma boa noção da sua organização, o que tem lá no geral, saber achar o que precisa ali. Tem que decorar o que usa mais e saber o que pode ser útil.

[Documentação do Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/). Não é exatamente a mesma do Android e esta versão ainda não está disponível nele.

Tem que aprender ler a documentação com cuidado, entender as minúcias. E precisa saber que nem tudo o que precisa saber sobre o uso daquela classe está escrito na documentação. Usar bem depende de experiência. Cada dia que usar bem, passará usar melhor no dia seguinte.

É possível encontrar outras documentações. Não sabe inglês? Terá dificuldade de desenvolver software em alto nível.

Procure outras fontes, confronte o que leu em algum lugar. Não aceite a primeira informação que recebe como uma verdade absoluta. Tenha uma atitude crítica e tenha certeza que entende todos fundamentos da computação para conseguir fazer isso com qualidade.

Algumas pessoas podem dar outras alternativas, mas a forma canônica de aprender algo é a documentação.

Na dúvida pergunte para quem é mais experiente.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!